# generate jasper report problem in jar file "Lorg"

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/jfree/chart/plot/PlotOrientation;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(Unknown Source)
```

hi guys i am new to jasper, trying to create a simple report with pie chart included jars jfreechart -1.0.0 and jcommon 1.0.0 please suggest what i am doing wrong , it has class file in org/jfree/chart/plot/PlotOrientation; but not in **Lorg**/jfree/chart/plot/PlotOrientation;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the dependencies (jars) are in your classpath. You can specify the classpath with the `java -cp /path/to/classes` switch. If this is a web application, put the dependent jars in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: how can i check which dependancy jar i am missing or see all dependancy jars

Comment: One option would be to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to automatically manage your dependenices. You may see a complete list of dependencies [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jasperreports/jasperreports/3.5.3), but I can't seem to be able to filter out the optional deps at the moment.